# WCF, HTTPS vs HTTP

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, ssl, https

There are two samples

#### For [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol):

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.ServiceModel.Security;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string addressHttps = String.Format("http://{0}:51222", Dns.GetHostEntry("").HostName);
            var wsHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            var serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof (HelloWorldService), new Uri(addressHttps));
            Type endpoint = typeof (IHelloWorldService);
            serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(endpoint, wsHttpBinding, "hello");
            Uri uri = new Uri(serviceHost.Description.Endpoints[0].ListenUri.AbsoluteUri + "/mex");
            var smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
            smb.HttpGetUrl = uri;
            serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Mex address  " + smb.HttpGetUrl);
            try
            {
                serviceHost.Open();
                string address = serviceHost.Description.Endpoints[0].ListenUri.AbsoluteUri;
                Console.WriteLine("Listening @ {0}", address);
                Console.WriteLine("Press enter to close the service");
                Console.ReadLine();
                serviceHost.Close();
            }
            catch (CommunicationException ce)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("A commmunication error occurred: {0}", ce.Message);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An unforseen error occurred: {0}", exc.Message);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IHelloWorldService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string SayHello(string name);
    }

    public class HelloWorldService : IHelloWorldService
    {
        #region IHelloWorldService Members

        public string SayHello(string name)
        {
            return string.Format("Hello, {0}", name);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

#### For [HTTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure)

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.ServiceModel.Security;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string addressHttps = String.Format("https://{0}:51222", Dns.GetHostEntry("").HostName);
            var wsHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            wsHttpBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;

            var serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof (HelloWorldService), new Uri(addressHttps));

            Type endpoint = typeof (IHelloWorldService);

            serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(endpoint, wsHttpBinding, "hello");

            serviceHost.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetCertificate(
                StoreLocation.LocalMachine,
                StoreName.My,
                X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "nameofsertificate");

            serviceHost.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Authentication.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;

            Uri uri = new Uri(serviceHost.Description.Endpoints[0].ListenUri.AbsoluteUri + "/mex");

            var smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            smb.HttpsGetEnabled = true;
            smb.HttpsGetUrl = uri;
            serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

            Console.Out.WriteLine("Mex address  " + smb.HttpsGetUrl);
            try
            {
                serviceHost.Open();

                string address = serviceHost.Description.Endpoints[0].ListenUri.AbsoluteUri;
                Console.WriteLine("Listening @ {0}", address);
                Console.WriteLine("Press enter to close the service");
                Console.ReadLine();
                serviceHost.Close();
            }
            catch (CommunicationException ce)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("A commmunication error occurred: {0}", ce.Message);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An unforseen error occurred: {0}", exc.Message);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        public static bool ValidateCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate cert, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        {
            if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors)
            {
                foreach (X509ChainStatus chainStatus in chain.ChainStatus)
                {
                    if (chainStatus.Status == X509ChainStatusFlags.Revoked)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    }

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IHelloWorldService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string SayHello(string name);
    }

    public class HelloWorldService : IHelloWorldService
    {
        #region IHelloWorldService Members

        public string SayHello(string name)
        {
            return string.Format("Hello, {0}", name);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

These samples are starting without errors, but if I try to create clients I have two different situations:

HTTP - the client was created successful using address

```
http://localhost:51222/hello/mex
```

And HTTPS failed. The address for HTTPS is:

```
https://localhost:51222/hello/mex
```

The error message for HTTPS is:

> There was an error downloading
>   `https://localhost:51222/hello/mex`.
>   The underlying connection was closed:
>   An unexpected error occurred on a
>   send. Authentication failed because
>   the remote party has closed the
>   transport stream. Metadata contains a
>   reference that cannot be resolved:
>   `https://localhost:51222/hello/mex`.
>   An error occurred while making the
>   HTTP request to
>   `https://localhost:51222/hello/mex`.
>   This could be due to the fact that the
>   server certificate is not configured
>   properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS
>   case. This could also be caused by a
>   mismatch of the security binding
>   between the client and the server. The
>   underlying connection was closed: An
>   unexpected error occurred on a send.
>   Authentication failed because the
>   remote party has closed the transport
>   stream. If the service is defined in
>   the current solution, try building the
>   solution and adding the service
>   reference again.

Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: Did you configure a server certificate for https?

Comment: Yes, the httpcfg query ssl returns next result
IP                      : 0.0.0.0:51222
Hash                    : c93258ff 776a9e43ef12f3f90b910521acd4989
Guid                    : {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
CertStoreName           : MY
CertCheckMode           : 0
RevocationFreshnessTime : 0
UrlRetrievalTimeout     : 0
SslCtlIdentifier        : (null)
SslCtlStoreName         : LOCAL_MACHINE
Flags                   : 0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found solution how to decided this problem. So, the correct code of server is:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string addressHttps = String.Format("https://{0}:9010", Dns.GetHostEntry("").HostName);
            var wsHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            wsHttpBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
            wsHttpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;
            var serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof (HelloWorldService), new Uri(addressHttps));
            Type endpoint = typeof (IHelloWorldService);
            serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(endpoint, wsHttpBinding, "hello");
            serviceHost.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetCertificate(
                StoreLocation.LocalMachine,
                StoreName.My,
                X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "sergiiz2");
            var smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            smb.HttpsGetEnabled = true;
            smb.HttpsGetUrl = new Uri(serviceHost.Description.Endpoints[0].ListenUri.AbsoluteUri + "/mex");
            serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
            Console.Out.WriteLine(smb.HttpsGetUrl);
            try
            {
                serviceHost.Open();

                string address = serviceHost.Description.Endpoints[0].ListenUri.AbsoluteUri;
                Console.WriteLine("Listening @ {0}", address);
                Console.WriteLine("Press enter to close the service");
                Console.ReadLine();
                serviceHost.Close();
            }
            catch (CommunicationException ce)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("A commmunication error occurred: {0}", ce.Message);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An unforseen error occurred: {0}", exc.Message);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IHelloWorldService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string SayHello(string name);
    }

    public class HelloWorldService : IHelloWorldService
    {
        #region IHelloWorldService Members

        public string SayHello(string name)
        {
            return string.Format("Hello, {0}", name);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

And a few cases related to certificate:
 - generating certificate:

```
makecert -r -pe -n "CN=%hostname%" -b 01/01/2000 -e 01/01/2050 -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -ss my -sr localMachine -sky exchange -sp "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider" -sy 12
```

- adding url to listening

  httpcfg set urlacl -u https://*:9010/ -a D:(A;;GX;;;S-1-5-21-1144070942-1563683482-3278297161-1114)
- say to the http.sys to know about ssl certificate on the port 9010

  httpcfg set ssl /i 0.0.0.0:9010 /h 8c6e12be5371860adfb84cd2ed2351a900731bb8  /g "{a2c24c79-b0ef-4783-8ed8-d93836fec137}"

  And all works without problems.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this answer: [How to programatically install an SSL certificate for a self-hosted WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292330/certificate-on-wcf-service-that-does-not-use-iis/5278348#5278348).

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you're making the httpsGetUri the same as your mex endpoint address? httpsGetUri is for publishing the WSDL, not servicing mex endpoints. You should clear that up.