# Check if the current user is administrator

Tags: c#, windows-administration

My application needs to run some scripts, and I must be sure that the user running them is an administrator... What is the best way of doing this using C#?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

```
using System.Security.Principal;

public static bool IsAdministrator()
{
    using (WindowsIdentity identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent())
    {
        WindowsPrincipal principal = new WindowsPrincipal(identity);
        return principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a note that the above will not work if UAC is enabled in Vista or Win7; you'll need to pop up a UAC confirmation box and elevate permissions in that case.

Comment: What's about http://ayende.com/blog/158401/are-you-an-administrator or http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2007/08/01/detecting-if-you-are-an-admin.aspx ? Which is better way ?

Comment: @AnkurTripathi Are you...?

Comment: That code won't work unless you run the app as administrator.

Answer (score 37):

```
return new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent())
    .IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
```

Comment: @Nissm: You both answered simultaneously, or near enough that 5 minutes after the fact you're both listed as having posted "5 minutes ago". There is no reason for you to attack Alex; we're not here to earn rep, we're here to help.

Comment: What's about http://ayende.com/blog/158401/are-you-an-administrator or http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2007/08/01/detecting-if-you-are-an-admin.aspx ? Which is better way ?

Answer (score 23):

You can also call into the Windows API to do this:

```
[DllImport("shell32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool IsUserAnAdmin();
```

which more generically tells you whether user is running under elevated rights.

Comment: This is by a factor of 25 the fastest method of doing this

Answer (score 16):

The above answers with ***IsInRole*** are actually correct: it does check if the current user has admin privilege.
However,

> Starting with Windows Vista, User Account Control (UAC) determines the privileges of a user. If you are a member of the Built-in Administrators group, you are assigned two run-time access tokens: a standard user access token and an administrator access token. By default, you are in the standard user role.

(from MSDN, e.g. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlogpermission(v=vs.110).aspx)

Thus, ***IsInRole*** will per default consider the user privilege, and thus the method return false. Only true when the software is explicitly run as administrator.

The other method checking AD in https://ayende.com/blog/158401/are-you-an-administrator will check if the user name is in an admin group.

My complete method combining both is thus:

```
    public static bool IsCurrentUserAdmin(bool checkCurrentRole = true)
    {
        bool isElevated = false;

        using (WindowsIdentity identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent())
        {
            if (checkCurrentRole)
            {
                // Even if the user is defined in the Admin group, UAC defines 2 roles: one user and one admin. 
                // IsInRole consider the current default role as user, thus will return false!
                // Will consider the admin role only if the app is explicitly run as admin!
                WindowsPrincipal principal = new WindowsPrincipal(identity);
                isElevated = principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
            }
            else
            {
                // read all roles for the current identity name, asking ActiveDirectory
                isElevated = IsAdministratorNoCache(identity.Name);
            }
        }

        return isElevated;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether the specified user is an administrator.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="username">The user name.</param>
    /// <returns>
    ///   <c>true</c> if the specified user is an administrator; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
    /// </returns>
    /// <seealso href="https://ayende.com/blog/158401/are-you-an-administrator"/>
    private static bool IsAdministratorNoCache(string username)
    {
        PrincipalContext ctx;
        try
        {
            Domain.GetComputerDomain();
            try
            {
                ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
            }
            catch (PrincipalServerDownException)
            {
                // can't access domain, check local machine instead 
                ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine);
            }
        }
        catch (ActiveDirectoryObjectNotFoundException)
        {
            // not in a domain
            ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine);
        }
        var up = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, username);
        if (up != null)
        {
            PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> authGroups = up.GetAuthorizationGroups();
            return authGroups.Any(principal =>
                                  principal.Sid.IsWellKnown(WellKnownSidType.BuiltinAdministratorsSid) ||
                                  principal.Sid.IsWellKnown(WellKnownSidType.AccountDomainAdminsSid) ||
                                  principal.Sid.IsWellKnown(WellKnownSidType.AccountAdministratorSid) ||
                                  principal.Sid.IsWellKnown(WellKnownSidType.AccountEnterpriseAdminsSid));
        }
        return false;
    }
```

For a user in an admin group without elevated privilege (UAC enabled), this method IsCurrentUserAdmin() return !checkCurrentRole: true if checkCurrentRole==false, but false if checkCurrentRole==true

If you run code that REQUIRES admin privilege, consider the checkCurrentRole==true. Otherwise, you'll get a security exception by then.
Therefore the correct ***IsInRole*** logic.

Comment: This is really nice but seems incomplete still.  What if the domain had global group that was ultimately a member of the local administrators group?  It doesn't seem like that would match up.  I can't test this today as I'm at home but maybe I'll play with it at work when I get back into the office.

Comment: This fits, but as the blog author says, it is too slow.

Comment: How does it work that you catch the exception when you try `ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine);` yet then again execute the same code in the next catch statement? Doesn't that crash the application?

Answer (score 8):

Like others here, my program is not running elevated, so this code returns `false` if UAC is enabled:

```
private bool IsCurrentUserAnAdmin()
{
    var principal = new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent());
    return principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
}
```

@EricBDev's answer with `IsAdministratorNoCache` does return `true` if my program is not running elevated, and the user is an Admin.  However, like the blog author says, it is very slow.

Here is my solution; it emulates `IsAdministratorNoCache` but is fast:

```
private bool IsCurrentUserInAdminGroup()
{
    // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/security-identifiers-in-windows
    // S-1-5-32-544
    // A built-in group. After the initial installation of the operating system,
    // the only member of the group is the Administrator account.
    // When a computer joins a domain, the Domain Admins group is added to
    // the Administrators group. When a server becomes a domain controller,
    // the Enterprise Admins group also is added to the Administrators group.
    var principal = new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent());
    var claims = principal.Claims;
    return (claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Value == "S-1-5-32-544") != null);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The answer by David Ching is good - but leaves you with a hardcoded ID for the Admin group.  This is a bit clearer:

```
private bool IsCurrentUserInAdminGroup()
{
    var claims = new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()).Claims;
    var adminClaimID = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.BuiltinAdministratorsSid, null).Value;
    return claims.Any(c => c.Value == adminClaimID);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just thought I'd add another solution; as the `IsInRole` doesn't always work.

- If the user isn't a member of the specified Windows User Group in the current session.
- The administrator has made changes in the Group Policy Settings
- The role parameter is treated as a 'Case Sensitive' method.
- And if an XP machine doesn't have the .NET Framework Version installed it won't work.

Depending on your needs if you need to support older systems; or are unsure of how your client is physically managing your system.  This is a solution I implemented; for flexibility and alterations.

```
class Elevated_Rights
    {

        // Token Bool:
        private bool _level = false;

        #region Constructor:

        protected Elevated_Rights()
        {

            // Invoke Method On Creation:
            Elevate();

        }

        #endregion

        public void Elevate()
        {

            // Get Identity:
            WindowsIdentity user = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();

            // Set Principal
            WindowsPrincipal role = new WindowsPrincipal(user);

            #region Test Operating System for UAC:

            if (Environment.OSVersion.Platform != PlatformID.Win32NT || Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major < 6)
            {

                // False:
                _level = false;

                // Todo: Exception/ Exception Log

            }

            #endregion

            else
            {

                #region Test Identity Not Null:

                if (user == null)
                {

                    // False:
                    _level = false;

                    // Todo: "Exception Log / Exception"

                }

                #endregion

                else
                {

                    #region Ensure Security Role:

                    if (!(role.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator)))
                    {

                        // False:
                        _level = false;

                        // Todo: "Exception Log / Exception"

                    }

                    else
                    {

                        // True:
                        _level = true;

                    }

                    #endregion


                } // Nested Else 'Close'

            } // Initial Else 'Close'

        } // End of Class.
```

So the above code has a few constructs; it will actually test to see if the User is on Vista or higher.  That way if a customer is on XP without a framework or beta framework from years ago it will allow you to alter what you'd like to do.

Then it will physically test to avoid a null value for the account.

Then last of all it will provide the check to verify that the user is indeed in the proper role.

I know the question has been answered; but I thought my solution would be a great addition to the page for anyone else whom is searching Stack. My reasoning behind the Protected Constructor would allow you to use this class as a Derived Class that you could control the state of when the class is instantiated.

Comment: What's about http://ayende.com/blog/158401/are-you-an-administrator or http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2007/08/01/detecting-if-you-are-an-admin.aspx ? Which is better way ?

Answer (score 0):

> I must be sure that the user running them is an administrator

If your application must be run with admin rights, it would be right to update its manifest.
Set `requestedExecutionlevel` to `requireAdminstrator`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I end up...
I'm forcing my app to run as administrator mode.
To do this

1- Add `<ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>` to your `csproj` file.

**MyProject.csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">    
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
  </PropertyGroup>    
</Project>
```

---

2- Add the below `app.manifest` file to your project.

**app.manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```