# C# Check if run as administrator

Tags: c#, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check if the current user is administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600322/check-if-the-current-user-is-administrator)

I need to test if the application (written in C#, running os Windows XP/Vista/7) is running as administrator (as in right-click .exe -> Run as Administrator, or Run as Administrator in the Compability tab under Properties).

I have googled and searched StackOverflow but i can not find a working solution.

My last attempt was this:

```
if ((new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()))
         .IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Is this a UAC thing? I.e. the user is already admin, but you want to know if app is elevated under UAC?

Comment: Not a duplicate. This question asks about the process, not about the logged in user.

Answer (score 171, accepted):

Try this

```
public static bool IsAdministrator()
{
    var identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
    var principal = new WindowsPrincipal(identity);
    return principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
}
```

This looks functionally the same as your code, but the above is working for me...

doing it functionally, (without unnecessary temp variables) ...

```
public static bool IsAdministrator()
{
   return (new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()))
             .IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
}
```

or, using expression-bodied property:

```
public static bool IsAdministrator =>
   new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent())
       .IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
```

Comment: Make sure to include "using System.Security.Principal;"

Comment: Worked for me on Windows 10.

Comment: You need to wrap it in a using statement: "using (var identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent())"

Comment: This is always true if the user is an Administrator. It does not distinguish elevated (run as Administrator, so poorly/confusingly worded by Microsoft).

Comment: This is only true if the user is Administrator and running the code elevated. In an Admin Command prompt, it will return true. In a non admin command prompt it will return false.

Comment: In my wpf application this returns true if i right click and 'Run as Admin' and returns false if i run it normally. So this checks both the user and the apps rights i think.

Comment: Best is the second option!

Comment: Accoding to Microsoft's documentation, IsInRole() method only determines whether the current principal belongs to a specified Windows user group (in this case Administrators), not whether process token is elevated.

Comment: Yup, works on Windows 10