# Faster method to test if (not current) user is an administrator

Tags: c#, windows, windows-security

I need to test which Windows users have administrator privileges.

OK, now read carefully: **NOT CURRENT USER**. I query all local user accounts, then I test which one of them has administrator privileges. Let's say I'm logged as Joe, my application runs in Joe user's context, but there is a user Timmy on this very PC, who is not currently logged on. I need to test if Timmy has admin on this PC. So, this question is definitely not about current user privileges ;) So, this is definitely not a duplicate of similar questions about determining the privileges of the current user. This one is different ;)

Here's my code:

```
public static dynamic[] Users => WMI.Query("SELECT * FROM Win32_UserAccount WHERE Disabled = 0").Select<dynamic, dynamic>(d => {
    var machineContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine);
    Principal principal = Principal.FindByIdentity(machineContext, d.SID);
    d.IsAdmin = principal.IsMemberOf(machineContext, IdentityType.Name, "Administrators");
    principal.Dispose();
    machineContext.Dispose();
    return d;
}).ToArray();
```

This works, but it takes **more than 2 seconds** to execute `IsMemberOf()`.
Is there a faster way to do this?
Why is it so slow?

If you wonder what `WMI.Query` does here, it just queries the WMI and returns result as an array of managed `dynamic` objects instead of `IDisposable` types. `IDisposable` types are disposed before the result is returned. Irrelevant to the question, though.

To clarify, I use `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` to get an actual user account from SID. I don't know if `WindowsIdentity` can be created from SID. AFAIK it can't. The user for `WindowsIdentity` needs to be logged on (throws a SecurityException if not), and I query all local users, not just the current one.

Comment: Did you try  `principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator)`?

Comment: This is not a `System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal`, its `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal`. There is no conversion between those 2 types I know of.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if the current user is administrator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600322/check-if-the-current-user-is-administrator)

Comment: @MatteoUmili Please read the question again, and notice that I don't ask about CURRENT user. I ask about ANY (not logged on) user on a Windows PC.

Comment: Please kindly read before commenting: I know how to check if CURRENT user is an administrator, what I'm asking is whether NOT THE CURRENT user is an administrator and this is a huge difference!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found it out, however it's still weird...

**Updated code:** (I changed matching group name to matching group SID).

```
public static dynamic[] Users => WMI.Query("SELECT * FROM Win32_UserAccount WHERE Disabled = 0").Select<dynamic, dynamic>(d => {
    using (var machineContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine))
    using (Principal principal = Principal.FindByIdentity(machineContext, d.SID))
    d.IsAdmin = principal.GetGroups().Any(i => i.Sid.IsWellKnown(System.Security.Principal.WellKnownSidType.BuiltinAdministratorsSid));
    return d;
}).ToArray();
```

It turns out `GetGroups()` is way faster than `IsMemberOf()`.

**Update:** It's actually roughly 135 times faster. `GetGroups()` with `Any()` took 17ms instead of 2300ms `IsMemberOf()` took.

As a bonus I'll share with my `WMI.Query` ;)

```
/// <summary>
/// Safe, managed WMI queries support.
/// </summary>
static class WMI {

/// <summary>
/// Queries WMI and returns results as an array of dynamic objects.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="q"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static dynamic[] Query(string q) {
    using (var s = new ManagementObjectSearcher(q))
        return
            s
            .Get()
            .OfType<ManagementObject>()
            .Select(i => {
                var x = new ExpandoObject();
                using (i) foreach (var p in i.Properties) (x as IDictionary<string, object>).Add(p.Name, p.Value);
                return x;
            })
            .ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: How much faster was it? From 2 seconds to ... ?

Comment: @Fildor From 2200ms to 17ms with diagnostic tools running ;)

Comment: `GetGroups` doesn't take nested groups into account.  That might be why it is faster, but it also means that the results may be incomplete, depending on the context.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Can local groups on Windows 10 be nested? Then, this magnitude of time difference seems to indicate something more happening than just a little more complex query. `System.DirectoryServices` is surely not limited to local groups, however the context is `Machine`. Maybe the local context itself is tested in network context? But it would make no sense in determining the access to local resources. It would make sense for a remote logon though.

Comment: Hmmm.  If it's a local account, and assuming the machine is not a domain controller, I don't think the groups can be nested.  So (ignoring pathological cases such as `INTERACTIVE` being in the Administrators group) you'll probably get accurate results from `.GetGroups`, except of course you should be checking the SIDs rather than looking at the strings.  But the delay in `.IsMember` might indeed be because it is checking the domain, though that doesn't really explain the delay.  Unless the query is timing out?