# how to implement ssl in a wcf rest service from a console client and a browser client

Tags: wcf, rest, console

i have a wcf rest service hosted on iis which is ssl enabled. i have both a console application and a browser as client. Is it possible to implement ssl on the console app? is possible, any idea or links to related resources will be greatly helpful.

Comment: This might be related to [this SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10274207/https-from-console-app/10373991#10373991)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use mutual SSL with a REST service from your console application, you can use the `WebChannelFactory` class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb908674.aspx

The client certificate is set using the `WebChannelFactory.Credentials` property. The advantage of this approach is that you can set the certificate in connnnfiguration so you can change it later without recompiling.

Alternatively, you can use the `HttpWebRequest` class and its `ClientCertificates` property.

Comment: Instead of using webclient, i wanted to work with the basics first.I am using httpwebrequest and httpwebresponse classes. It will be helpful if you could clarify more or provide some links to related resources.If i want to enable ssl on the console app(so that the server knows it is the actual client it is talking to), how do i do that? what are the classes and libraries in C# that deals with ssl.

Comment: Do you mean you want to do mutual SSL between the client and server?

Comment: also i get the following error when i host my service in a console application.HTTP could not register URL https://+:443/Service1.svc/ because TCP port 443 is being used by another application.

Comment: That sounds like you are *hosting* the service in your console app. I understood from your question that the service was hosted in IIS and the console app was the client? If you try to host the service in a console app ona  machine that has IIS on it, you will usually need to specify an alternative port because IIS will be listening for HTTPS traffic on port 443.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mike. It worked.  Just very much amazed to see that if one wants a ssl enabled service and not the client, configuring the service does it all. But does does all the inner workings of ssl happen? this is something i really need to look upon. Thanks again.

Comment: My service(ssl+basic) and client(browser) are working properly.but authentication is done for all the requests(GET,PUT,POST,DELETE). However i want that authentication should be done for all except GET. How do i do that?

Comment: to be more specific, the service is hosted in IIS

Comment: The authentication scheme in WCF is specified at the service level so you can't pick which verbs you want to apply it to. You could place the GET in a different service...