# SSL Self Cert not trusted or invalid IIS 7 when trying to access a https wcf rest service

Tags: wcf, iis, ssl

I am having trouble applying a self certificate, which I have generated via IIS 7 and moved to the Trusted Certificate folder. When I type in the https URL to the web service for example,

```
 https://localhost:9000/mywebservice/aservice/GetMyData
```

I get back that the certificate is not trusted or not valid plus I get a http 404 response.

In my endeavours to get this working, I have been following the examples given in the following links:

http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/how-to-set-up-ssl-on-iis

http://www.allenconway.net/2012/05/creating-wcf-restful-service-and-secure.html

http://www.allenconway.net/2011/06/create-self-signed-ssl-certificate.html

All I am trying to do by configuration is to host a WCF Rest Service returning a JSON response in IIS with a certificate generated off the local machine. I thought this should be relatively simple, but there seems to be some wrong turns being made. So, if anyone can give me some pointers as to what I can do solve this, I would be grateful.

Thanks

Comment: did you Register and map WCF port(9000) with netsh if Not then follow this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10274207/https-from-a-console-application/10373991#10373991

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Firefox, it's got its own certificate store so you'll have to add your self signed certificate there too.

Comment: Not using Firefox - IE 11

Answer (score 0):

Is the Subject Name of the SSL certificate localhost?

Comment: No the name is Local Machine

Comment: The CN in the certificate has to match the URL, e.g. if the URL is https://localhost:9000/mywebservice/aservice/GetMyData, then CN should be localhost as well.